# Calculate the distance within php or js?

Tags: javascript, database, google-maps, client-server, distance

First of all, I am not sure this question should be in stackoverflow or other stackexchange network. So if wrong place just move for me.

It is better to calculate the distance between 2 points of lat/lng in DB or js?
Since Google maps provide computeDistanceBetween(). This is really easy to use, but i am thinking if i have 10000 rows and only 5 rows are within the distance and to display into the map.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is only about where it should be calculated then I prefer client side. It is simple, fast, more flexible and dinamic, and you unload your server.

Comment: Ok, for example.
I have a center point marker and i have 10k rows lat/lng in Asia, 10k rows in Europe. Then i want to get the lat/lng within 10KM to center point marker over the 20k rows. So this is better to do the calculation on DB or js.

Erm, I got another question here. If the center point already known at Asia then how can I just query the 10k rows instead of 20k rows?

Comment: Some databases have this built in, it is called an r-tree index. I would recommend looking into the geospatial tools in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about your problem, I'd probably go with doing calculation-intensive tasks on the client side (or "in JS"). This will never put too much load on your server-side application, by distributing it among clients.

Of course there are many variables you have to take into account to choose the best approach.

Other things you may consider:

- doing it server-side and caching the results,
- using google-api and also caching it on your server,
- many many more...

Answer (score 0):

It depends to the frequency of calculations.
If your points are permanent then you can calculate all required distances only once before inserting the row into table and save the calculated result to provide it to clients later.
But if calculations are repeatable and coordinates of points will be changed eventually then it's better to use client-side calculations.
Really it's not that hard task for browser to execute some JavaScript which will calculate distances even for a lot of points.
Also if you have really tons of input data you can consider some background pre-calculations on client-side and caching of results in localStorage* so your users will never wait.

*** [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) could help you to ensure cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Where it is better to calculate distance is completely dependent on your application. If you the client has the information then it is better in JS.

In this scenario you appear to be trying to calculate the nearest points stored in your database to a given point. This is most certainly better handled by the database using geospatial indexes.

The typical algorithm narrows down the result set with a unsophisticated approach. Within x & y +/- 10KM and then with that result set do a full calculation.

I would say if your information is in the database then look into using built in geospatial tools for your DBMS.